# What event is called when an admin user is deleted

Tags: magento-1.9, user, delete

I want to call an observer function whenever an admin user is deleted. Could please tell me if there is any event called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of these events `admin_user_delete_before` or `admin_user_delete_after` or `admin_user_delete_commit_after`.
The third one is outside the transaction.
So if you have an error in your code, or you want to throw an exception, the first 2 will not delete the user, but the third one will.
The events are triggered from the `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::_beforeDelete`, `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::_afterDelete` and `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::_afterDeleteCommit`.
this is the parent class for the `Mage_Admin_Model_User` class.

Answer (score 0):

I think safe event is admin_user_delete_commit_after.
Because the delete & commit flow like this

```
        $this->_beforeDelete();
        $this->_getResource()->delete($this);
        $this->_afterDelete();
        $this->_getResource()->commit();
        $this->_afterDeleteCommit();
```

If any exception occurs in first 3 lines it will roll back.But after commit its not possible.